# create boolean column based on verified condition

Tags: python, search

Hello I'd like to create a Boolean column based on condition. I've created dictionary which has Region as Key and postal code as value. In my data set I've
extracted the two first digit of postal code of customers. I want to check if my customers has the same postal code of the Region.
Both of these two method don't give me good results. I get all values to `False`.

```
data_pct = pd.read_csv('../data_out/data.csv', sep=';', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
data_pct = data_pct.reset_index(drop=True)
data_pct['top_posclt'] = ''
dic_codeclub = {
    'R1': '33',
    'R2': '34',
    'R3': '19',
    'R4': '56',
    'R5': '47',
    'R6': '31',
    'R7': '06',
}

data_pct['basePOSCLT'] = ''
for i in range(0, data_pct.shape[0]):
    data_pct['basePOSCLT'][i] = str(data_pct['POSCLT'][i])[0:2]
data_pct['basePOSCLT'] = data_pct.basePOSCLT.fillna(0) # for customer with no Adress
```

**First method:**

```
data_pct['top_posclt1'] = data_pct['basePOSCLT'].apply(lambda x: True if x in list(dic_codeclub.values()) else False)
```

**Second Method:**

```
for i in data_pct['basePOSCLT']:
    for j in list(dic_codeclub.values()):
        data_pct['top_posclt2'] =  'True' if i == j else 'False'
```

`data_pct['top_poscltX']` has only `False`. How should I make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I understood your question wrong but if you want to check if a specific value exists in a dict, you can use the methods `.keys()` and `.values()` and then do a `is in` comparison like so: `'R2' in test_dict.keys()` and `'99' in test_dict.values()` respectively

```
test_dict = {
    'R1': '33',
    'R2': '34',
    'R3': '19',
    'R4': '56',
    'R5': '47',
    'R6': '31',
    'R7': '06',
}

print(f"Key 'R2'  is in dict:  {'R2' in test_dict.keys()}")
print(f"Key 'ABC' is in dict:  {'ABC' in test_dict.keys()}")
print("")
print(f"Value '33' is in dict: {'33' in test_dict.values()}")
print(f"Value '99' is in dict: {'99' in test_dict.values()}")
```

Comment: Hello, not to veirfy if Ri is in but the value of basecode `data_pct['basePOSCLT'][i]` if it's in dict values then create bool True or False..

Comment: So what happens if you do `data_pct['basePOSCLT'][i] in dic_codeclub.values()` ?

Comment: Where? I have'nt use that.

Comment: This is why I asked what happens if you do so :)

Comment: Where you do want I try it, in second method? It's running I'm waiting results.

Comment: I get only False again.

Comment: Sorry my first method worked, i just chnaged the type of dict values. to str. as wrtten in the post. i did not include ' '.